# Recovering from org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException without access to a Hibernate session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I have a situation where more then one thread can modify the same object (they modify different fields, so it is not a problem). I detected possible problem with the following approach:

```
Contact contact = someService.getMeAContactSomeHow(..);

try {
  //force hibernate to initialize contact's collections
  Hibernate.initialize(contact);
} catch (StaleObjectStateException e) {
  session.evict(contact);
  //reload the contact object with up to date version property
  contact = contactDao.get(contact.getId());
}

//continue working with contact as nothing has happened.
```

But I cannot use this approach if I don't have access to a hibernate session. For example I am working with the contact object in a controller's helper class (which basically shouldn't have access to the hibernate session).

How can I replicate the same behaviour but without access to the Hibernate session?

Comment: Modifying an entity in different threads is a problem. Changes trigger code in hibernate which is not thread safe. Without synchronization there is no guarantee when and if your changes make it to the database.

Comment: Are you sure you could use this approach event if you had access to the `Session`? Is `StaleObjectStateException` recoverable, will you be able to commit the transaction after you catch one?